# Is there a way to safely eject a USB hard drive from the lock screen?

Tags: usb, screen-lock, eject

Often I come to my mac sitting on my desk in the morning and need to simply unplug it and put it in a bag. While maybe not strictly necessary to properly eject the attached USB drive, it sure would be nice if there were a way to do so without first logging in.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no save way to eject an external drive from the lock screen.

You have several options though:

1. Purchase and install [Mountain](http://appgineers.de/mountain/) and enable "Unmount external volumes on sleep". The feature still seems to be experimental.
2. Create a LaunchDaemon which ejects your external drive(s) gracefully at say 5am. Here is an example of a bash script to start with:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   /usr/sbin/diskutil list | grep -e 'disk[1-9]s.*' | sed 's/.*\(disk[0-9].*\)/\1/' | xargs -I{}
   /usr/sbin/diskutil unmount {}
   ```

   If you don't want to write a LaunchDaemon, [Sleepwatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/sleepwatcher_2.2.tgz) should support your efforts.
3. Unmount all external volumes before setting your Mac(s) to sleep.

Comment: Thanks for all that.  Holding out in hopes someone does have a direct answer.  1-3 aren't ideal.